# Prolog result not store

Tags: prolog

problem
i want addition store in fresult from the rules

code:

```
gresult:-
    write('enter first number'),nl,
    read(P),nl,
     write('enter second number'),nl,
    read(Q),nl,
     write('adition result is'),nl,
     fresult(P,Q),nl,
     write(fresult).

fresult(P,Q):-
       P+Q.
```

Comment: Please formalize your code and describe your expected results clearly

Comment: problem i want adition store in fresult from the rules

code:

gresult:-

write('enter first number'),nl,
read(P),nl,
 write('enter second number'),nl,
read(Q),nl,
 write('adition result is'),nl,
 fresult(P,Q),nl,
 write(fresult).
fresult(P,Q):- P+Q.

Comment: `fresult(P,Q) :- P+Q.` is creating a term `P+Q` that doesn't go anywhere. You probably want to do something more like `Result is P+Q, asserta(result(Result))`, then you can get to it later by doing `result(Result)`. But of course it is gross to use `asserta/1` if it isn't totally necessary, are you just wanting to print it? In that case just do `Result is P+Q, write(Result), nl.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want `fresult` to "return" a value, you must add one more parameter for it:

```
fresult(P, Q, Sum) :-
    Sum is P + Q.
```

Note that you must use the `is` operator to force Prolog to treat `P + Q` as an arithmetic expression and evaluate it to a number.

Then you can call it like this:

```
gresult :-
    ...,
    fresult(P, Q, Sum),
    write(Sum),
    nl.
```